# Insufficient privilege DBMS_SCHEDULER job

Tags: oracle, jobs, privileges, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I have created a job in Oracle using following scheduler -

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'MY_JOB',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'BEGIN my_pkg.pull_data(''Y''); END;',
    start_date      => '31-AUG-21 07.00.00 PM America/New_York',
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
/
```

When I am running job manually using below code -

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(
    JOB_NAME            => 'MY_JOB',
    USE_CURRENT_SESSION => FALSE);
END;
```

The job is running as expected. However, scheduled same jobs are failed again and again with below error.

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.MY_PKG", line 246 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Any suggestion, what I am doing wrong? I think I have sufficient privileges.
Edit - If I call, individual procedure which is used in the job, it's working as expected. I have checked the line 246, which is a select statement from a table in the same schema as job, proc and other tables used by the proc.

```
BEGIN my_pkg.pull_data('Y'); END;
```

Comment: Check line 246 of `MY_PKG`. Whatever your program is having problems with is there.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. I already have checked it. It's a select statement from a table in the same schema. Moreover, if I run the job manually as I mentioned in my question, it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: With the manual job run (which works) what happens if you run it after issuing "set role none"